# How did it compute the gradient of Bayesian expression?

Tags: probability, bayesian, bayes-theorem

From Bayes Theorem:

\begin{equation}
p(x|y) = \frac{p(x) p(y|x)}{p(y)} =\frac{p(x) p(y|x)}{\int p(x) p(y|x)}
\end{equation}

If we take gradients with respect to $x$ in both sides of the equation we obtain:
\begin{equation}
\nabla_x \log p(x|y) = \nabla_x \log p(x) + \nabla_x \log p(y|x)
\end{equation}

Someone could explain me how did he reach here? My level of math is not very high but as far as I understand after applying the chain rule I got the following expression:

\begin{equation}
\nabla_x \log p(x|y) = \frac{p(y|x)}{p(y)}\nabla_x \log p(x) + \frac{p(x)}{p(y)}\nabla_x \log p(y|x)
\end{equation}

Comment: Please can you supply context of where you read this, preferably a link. What I think is going on here is that $p(y)$ does not contain $x$, can be treated as a constant, and therefore vanishes when you take the derivative with respect to $x$. So no need for the chain rule. However, I cannot be sure enough of this to write an answer unless I see the original context.

Comment: @Jack Gallagher's reason that *"you can safely assume that $p(y)$ is not a function of $x$ otherwise Bayes theorem would not work"* is completely correct. Any additional information in the further context you would have supplied cannot violate Bayes theorem. On that basis there is no longer as urgent a necessity to supply further context.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

He's just using the properties of logarithms, then differentiating.

\begin{align}
p(x|y) &= \frac{p(x) p(y|x)}{p(y)}\\
\implies\log{p(x|y)} &= \log{\frac{p(x) p(y|x)}{p(y)}}\\
&= \log{p(x)} + \log{p(y|x)} - \log{p(y)}\\
\implies \nabla_x\log{p(x|y)} &= \nabla_x\log{p(x)} + \nabla_x\log{p(y|x)} - \nabla_x\log{p(y)}\\
 &= \nabla_x\log{p(x)} + \nabla_x\log{p(y|x)}\\
\end{align}

because $p(y)$ is constant with respect to $x$. Probabilists make it clear when a function $p$ is a function of multiple variables. You can safely assume that $p(y)$ is not a function of x; indeed if it were, Bayes's Theorem would not apply.

Answer (score 0):

A more detailed proof would go as follows:

$ \nabla_x \log p(x|y) = \nabla_x (\log p(x|y) + \log p(y))= 
\nabla_x (\log p(x|y) p(y)) = \nabla_x (\log p(x, y)) = \nabla_x (\log p(x) p(y | x)) = \nabla_x \log p(x) + \nabla_x \log p(y | x) $